# AngularJs Error: [$injector:unpr] while attempting to inject $httpProvider to a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'll try to keep it short. Basically I have this module...

```
var mod1= angular.module("mod1", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
```

then a service, an interceptor, a factory and a controller...

```
mod1.service("sessionService", sessionService);
mod1.factory("loginFactory", loginFactory);
mod1.controller("accountController", accountController);
```

The `sessionService` is in a separate file which basically exposes a few functions to session info in local storage...

```
var sessionService = function ($httpProvider) {
    return {
        startSession: function (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('so_acc_token', token.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('so_acc_token_type', token.token_type);

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token.token_type + " " + token.access_token;
        },

        //a couple more functions, removed for clarity
        ...
    }
}

sessionService.$inject = ["$httpProvider"];
```

Now, the `loginFactory` (on supposedly many more modules and factories) calls/depends on this "singleton" service. It is also located in a separate file and looks like this...

```
var loginFactory = function ($http, $q, sessionService) {
    return function (u, p, g, c) {

        var deferredObject = $q.defer();
        var data = { grant_type: g, username: u, password: p };
        var transformRequest = function (d) {
            var t = [];

            for (var k in d) {
                t.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(d[k]));
            }

            return t.join("&");
        };

        $http.post('http://whatever_url/token', 
            transformRequest(data), {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            //sessionService.startSession(data);
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
        })
        .error(function () {
            //sessionService.endSession();
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
        });

        return deferredObject.promise;
    }
}

loginFactory.$inject = ["$http", "$q", "sessionService"];
```

and finally account controller is invoked when a specific route is hit...the controller looks like this...

```
var accountController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, loginFactory) {
    $scope.loginForm = {
        userName: '',
        password: '',
        grant_type: 'password',
        loginFailure: false
    };

    $scope.signIn = function () {
        var result = loginFactory($scope.loginForm.userName,
            $scope.loginForm.password,
            $scope.loginForm.grant_type);

        result.then(function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                    $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                }
                else {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            }
            else {
                $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
            }
        });
    };

};

accountController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', "$location", "loginFactory"];
```

However, when the `signIn` method is invoked from the `accountController` I get the following error...

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24httpProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24httpProvider%20%3C-<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">essionService%20%3C-%20loginFactory
```

I think it's got to do with the way I'm inject `$httpProvider` to the service but  I'm struggling to understand why. So, my question is...

#### What exactly did I get wrong here? And Why?

P.S. I'm sorry for the length of the question but I wanted to add some context to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providers can only be used during the configuration phase. Once that phase is done, services are created from the providers, and providers can't be used anymore.
So injecting a provider in a service is not possible.

To solve your specific problem, just inject the $http service: the headers can be configured on the service directly. [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The defaults can also be set at runtime via the $http.defaults object in the same fashion. For example:
>
> ```
> module.run(function($http) {
>     $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
> });
> ```

Comment: wow!! So obvious! Thanks, mate. I think I need a break from the computer